# Pull up to present a UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller

How do i mimic that pull to present a `UIImagePickerController` (when the phone is locked) ? I think i know how to do so with regular view (using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and `UIKit` dynamics) . I would be glad for some tips + if there is some library that does the same thing >

Also where do i get that camera icon ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is system feature. Apple only, you could not do it when the device is locked. You could only achieve this in your **own** app.

Maybe you could do this on a jailbreaked device.